# Use custom _id value

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a database of users who all have a unique ID (Java UUID) to differentiate them as the other data (firstname, IP and lastname) can contain duplicates. Is it a good idea to set _id to the unique id as this would save me from creating and indexing another field and having a useless _id field.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @atishshimpi "Is it a good idea to set _id to the unique id as this would save me from creating and indexing another field and having a useless _id field."

Comment: This is totally fine in MongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

This is a debatable topic and specifics vary depending on database engine.  I'll speak more generally assuming the database engine may possibly change at a later point in time.  To help you decide, here are some pros and cons for using a UUID as the row's ID:

Pros:

- Unique across tables where data is distinct but similar in nature
- Makes moving from one database engine to another very straight forward as a row's ID is not entirely dependant on time of insertion

Cons:

- Disallows elegant clustered indexing as UUID's are not sequential.  This means when you do an insert, your database will have to reshuffle a high amount of memory pages to retain order(some database engines such as SQL Server create an "uniquifier" field to work around this but in the end, costs the same as using an int as the primary key)

  - Makes debugging within an application or log file much more difficult as an int field is easier to compare/look at than a UUID
  - Joins against tables are slower verses int, true for most all database implementations

My personal advice would be to use an int for your ID.  Your joins will be quicker against tables and overall much easier to debug.  You of course can still have the UUID be a foreign key but as your solution scales up, small easy to view values will come in handy.